# How to make trellis plots based on index in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pivot-table, subplot

I have a data like this:

```
Site, DayOfYear, Temp1, Temp2
Loc1, 1, 23.1, 24.2
Loc1, 2, 24.5, 25.3
...,  ...
Loc1, 365, 23.1, 21.6
Loc2, 1, 23.5, 25.6
Loc2, 2, ...
...., ...
Loc3, 1, ...
........
```

What I want to do is to make plot of `temp1` and `temp2` (overlaid on each other) throughout a year (DOY from 1 to 365) for each Site. I tried various ways but didn't get through.

Comment: You said you tried various ways ... what did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: A "trellis plot" can mean a lot of different things.  Your description makes it sound as though you want `plt.plot(day_of_year, temp_1); plt.plot(day_of_year, temp_2)`.  However, this wouldn't be a trellis plot in the way the term is normally used (plotting different bins of a third variable).  Can you elaborate or show a sketch of what you have in mind?